# how to create a zero-copy, no-capacity, blocking pipe in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I know the concept sounds a little abusive (?), but still - how can I create a pipe in bash which:

1. has no capacity
2. and therefore requires no memory copy, and
3. requires the write to be blocking

Comment: There has to be _some_ capacity for the cross-process transfer buffer, no?  Are you expecting the reading thread to reach into the address space of the sending process to get the data?

Comment: Why? What's the goal? To answer, you can't. Bash doesn't provide an `fcntl`.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/281897/is-there-a-device-file-that-just-blocks maybe?

Comment: @Mat - thanks, but I think it still copies data into the FIFO

Comment: @ormaaj - to save some development time :)

Comment: Zero-copy will require shared memory and involve you doing the synchronization. That will certainly _increase_ your dev time.

Comment: I guess the question is really is there some command line utility like, say "mkshm <size>" that created a pseudo-file that is backed up by shared memory?

Comment: I guess you're right, @Mat. I cannot avoid copying if I want to leave the two processes oblivious to the fact that this memory is shared.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing a lot here.  But possibly you are thinking about coprocesses and do not know what that term means.

bash supports coprocesses:
`http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html`

```
    The format for a coprocess is:

    coproc [NAME] command [redirections]

    This creates a coprocess named NAME. 
If NAME is not supplied, the default name is COPROC.

NAME must not be supplied if command is a simple command (see Simple Commands); 

otherwise, it is interpreted as the first word of the simple command.
```

When the coproc is executed, the shell creates an array variable (see Arrays) named NAME in the context of the executing shell.  The standard output of command is connected via a pipe to a file descriptor in the executing shell, and that file descriptor is assigned to NAME[0].

The standard input of command is connected via a pipe to a file descriptor in the executing shell, and that file descriptor is assigned to NAME[1].

This pipe is established before any redirections specified by the command (see Redirections).

The file descriptors can be utilized as arguments to shell commands and redirections using standard word expansions.

Comment: Thanks! That's a cool feature that I did not know about - but it is not what I was looking for (see my comment to Mat in the question)